# How to setup magento 2 when shipping fee is charged for each warehouse (source)

Tags: magento2, shipping, source, calculate

We are considering how to setup magento 2 when shipping fee is charged for each warehouse (source) . One type of product is basically assigned to one warehouse in our system. But, if you buy multiple types of products from different warehouses at once, the shipping fee will be the total shipping cost for each warehouse.(Also the shipping fee doesn't depend on the quantity of the products.)

For example if there is Product A (which is assigned to warehouse 1 and the shipping fee is 8$) and Product B (which is assigned to warehouse 2 and the shipping fee is 8$) , the total shipping fee will be 16$ when buying them at once, 8$ when buying either of them.

How can we do this in magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question.
Any suggestions?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/207742)